# On Ubuntu an executable created with Pyinstaller doesn't run

Tags: ubuntu, pyinstaller

I am on ubuntu 16.04. I am trying to make an executable from my python script (`fez.py`) using pyinstaller using `pyinstaller --onefile fez.py`.

The executable gets built without any error. I get the two folders dist and build with the `.exe` file in dist. I get the `fez.spec` file too.
But when I try to run the executable nothing seems to happen.

**My question is:**

Is there a problem with the pyinstaller process to create the executable that doesn't get displayed as an error OR is there a problem with my ubuntu that it can't run the executable? Whichever is the reason how to run my executable?

NB: I am well versed with the fact that pyinstaller is OS specific i.e. for an executable to work on ubuntu it should be prepared on ubuntu itself and that is exactly what I have done. I have used the pyinstaller command on ubuntu. This also rules out the fact that I should install wine or something else of that sort as wine is required to **execute windows executables on ubuntu.** (Files with .exe extension) The executable I am making using pyinstaller on ubuntu specifically **builds executables for ubuntu.** (In properties they show application\x-executable)

**EDIT:** To run the executable I had to first change the permission to allow as executable. Then I had to run from the terminal. But is there no way to run it using double clicks.

Comment: If you open the executable from the command line, will it produce an error? If so, could you please add it to your question as an edit?

Comment: @apogalacticon I'm honestly not sure how others expect others to bug fix when no one posts errors.  I find it's super difficult to provide any sort of assistance.  It's really quite simple.  CD <DIRECTORY HERE>.  kk.exe.   At least for windows.  This usually will display in command line what is going on so appropriate action can be taken to combat it rather than saying along the lines of there is no error message I'm lost, use psychic abilities to fix this for me.

Comment: No, it doesn't produce an error when executed from command line. @apogalacticon

Comment: Run in a terminal on the command line. Give any error message in your question. Perhaps use [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) to understand what system calls have been done (and some might failed). You probably need to improve your Python script to check more system errors.

Comment: BTW, on Linux and every Unix the usual way to run programs is thru the command line, or thru some other program doing [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html). Your graphical desktop is only an imperfect illusion: I have nearly 7000 executables on my Linux, and only a few hundreds of them are runnable from the GUI (without command line)..

Comment: Without much more details and some [MCVE] your question is unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across this issue, and I know this is an old post, but since it seems relevant and the first return in google for my problem I'll add since I spent a bit of time on this. The issue is that most files that don't have an extension are treated as text files, or some other MIME-Type, even if they are marked as executable. Running from the shell is one workaround but this is rather clunky. Here is my takeaway and my solution. I don't think Linux has any sort of "this is an executable" extension so if you want your GUI (eg gnome or whatever) to see the file as an application/executable file you have to set the mime type for that type of file. For me what I did was register .run as an executable mime-type. I have a .xml file that is used to register the new mime-type and then a .sh script that I can share with friends to do the same.

So I have three files:

- GCUL.RUN (The PyInstaller single file)
- run-mime-type.xml
- enable-run-mime-type.sh (ran as sudo)

And here are the contents of the .xml and .sh file. Once this is done, I can double click on the binary just like I would in windows and it opens.

**run-mime-type.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mime-info xmlns='http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/shared-mime-info'>
<mime-type type="application/x-executable">
    <comment>Executable Binary File</comment>
    <comment xml:lang="en">English</comment>
    <glob pattern="*.run"/>
</mime-type>
</mime-info>
```

**enable-run-mime-type.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE=/usr/share/mime/packages/run-mime-type.xml
if test -f "$FILE"
then
    echo "$FILE already found, aborting!"
else
    cp run-mime-type.xml /usr/share/mime/packages
    update-mime-database /usr/share/mime
fi

if test -f "$FILE"
then
    echo "$FILE copied, updating MIME-Type database..."
    echo "MIME-Type database has been updated!"
else
    echo "$FILE not found, something went wrong..."    
fi
```

Depending on your system you might have to change some path's but I think this would work for any Ubuntu-based OS running a Gnome variant, possibly others as well. What I am doing is copying the mime-type configuration .xml to the directory used to register mime-types and then updating the mime database.

***Hope that helps someone.***

Answer (score 6):

To execute the fez executable from terminal, go to the folder containing the executable (i.e: `/home/user/dist` folder) and run the below command in terminal (here the executable is called `fez` is the name of the executable):

```
~/dist$ ./fez
```

After executing the command if your script has any print statements then the statements are displayed in the terminal. Even if you executable or script has any errors, they are displayed in terminal.

Comment: In my case ~/dist$ was redundant. Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Comment: it never worked for me all it gave me is [14330] Failed to Execute Script 'gui' due to unhandled exeption

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly how to do it... but I believe you can create a .desktop file that sets parameters like terminal = [true/false] and command = "/path/to/executable" or something like that. Then you can double click the .desktop file and it will execute your program. I've never tried this... just read about it a while back. Maybe google .desktop files and see if that leads you anywhere...

Answer (score 0):

You have to change chmod of the app. (For example `chmod 777 custom_app_filename`)

I believe it will work then.
Chmod command changes the permissions of one file
for example
1chmod a+x filename` makes the filename file to be executable

Reference lik: https://linuxize.com/post/chmod-command-in-linux/